# In ./vscode/launch.json how set --bundle-sksl-path flutter_01.sksl.json

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

in launch.json set --bundle-sksl-path not work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RE7Hb.png)

```
"args": [
                "--bundle-sksl-path",
                "flutter_01.sksl.json",
                "--no-dds",
            ]
"args": [
                "--bundle-sksl-path=flutter_01.sksl.json",
                "--no-dds",
            ]
```

both no work;

but `flutter run  --bundle-sksl-path flutter_01.sksl.json` is work

should be the same as  `flutter run  --bundle-sksl-path flutter_01.sksl.json`